# Command is not found

Tags: shell-script, test

I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash
read num
sum=0
i=1
while [$i -le $num]; do
    let sum=$sum+1
    let i=$i+1
done
echo $sum
```

I am getting the error ./test: line 5: [1: command not found , but I am not sure what part of this is wrong and can not be found.

Comment: `[ $i -le $num ]`. Note the spaces.

Comment: The spaces have to be on both sides of the variables and operators?

Comment: Yes. `[` is a command, and it requires `]` as its last argument. Note that the assignment *must not* have a space on either side (as you correctly have it now).

Comment: here you go : #!/bin/bash
set -x # this will print every step of the excution process

sum=0
i=1
while [ $i -le "$@" ]; do
    sum+=1
    i+=1
done
echo $sum